# How to Specify field MongoDB Definition dynamically using a string in F#

Tags: mongodb, f#

I started out using quite strongly typed definitions

```
let coll: IMongoCollection<NZPostDataItem> = MongoUtil.getNzpostCollection()
let filter = Builders<NZPostDataItem>.Filter.And(
        Builders<NZPostDataItem>.Filter.Gte((fun n -> n.dateLodged),DateTime(2020,10,1)),
        Builders<NZPostDataItem>.Filter.Eq((fun n -> n.eshipMatched.Value) , true)
)// ... etc
```

The problem is, I need to dynamically run a query because one of the objects contains a BSONDocument

```
    let coll: IMongoCollection<NZPostDataItem> = MongoUtil.getNzpostCollection()
    let t = Nullable<bool> true
    let filter = 
        FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.op_Implicit(
            "{
            eshipMatched:true, 
            'eship.order.carrier_service_code':'TDEAUS',
            dateLodged: {$gte: new Date('01-Oct-2020')}}
            )"
        )
```

Which works directly on MongoDB.  But when I try and query it, I get a compile time error.

```
let results = coll.Find(filter).Limit(10000).ToList<NZPostDataItem>()
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0041  No overloads match for method 'Find'.

Known type of argument: FilterDefinition

```
Available overloads:
 - (extension) IMongoCollection.Find<'TDocument>(filter: FilterDefinition<'TDocument>,?options: 
FindOptions) : IFindFluent<'TDocument,'TDocument> // Argument 'filter' doesn't match
 - (extension) IMongoCollection.Find<'TDocument>(filter: 
Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<'TDocument,bool>>,?options: FindOptions) : 
IFindFluent<'TDocument,'TDocument> // Argument 'filter' doesn't match
```

So - I can sort of see what is wrong - maybe 2 types of definitions - but I need to filter dynamically but return a strongly typed object.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want the filter to be both dynamic and strongly-typed, so that's what you should create:

```
let filter = 
    FilterDefinition<NZPostDataItem>.op_Implicit("{ ... }")
```